# How can I weigh the compound that melts at room temperature?

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, synthesis

I am conducting an organic synthesis experiment involving 2,3,5-tribromothiophene.
The melting point of 2,3,5-tribromothiophene is about 25-28 ℃, so it melts easily during weighing.
Whenever I weigh this compound, it melts soon and wet the weighing paper. So there arises big uncertainty in weight of compound. How can I weigh the compound that melts at room temperature and move it to the reactor with minimum loss? Is there no other way but to weigh as quickly as possible?

Comment: How about using a plastic weighing boat and flush the sample into the reactor with the corresponding solvent?

Comment: Weigh it as a liquid, pipette it into a tared vial, dissolve in reaction solvent and add to reactor.

Comment: Similar to weighting boats of plastic or glass, a [watch glass](https://chemglass.com/watch-glass-pyrex?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) may do the job, too.  Depending on scale and design of the balance, a beaker (there are already ones for about 20 mL) may do the job, too.

Comment: @andselisk Yes, but not with dichloromethane... Learnt that the hard way!

Comment: @orthocresol On the positive side, you also discover a nice "glue" for many plastics;)